# Execute cmd.exe from Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd

Environment:
Windows Host running Vagrant and VirtualBox
Installed Ubuntu 64 Vagrant Box with Vagrant
NodeJS is running on the Vagrant box

Hello, I was wondering if it is possible to run 'cmd.exe' from within the Vagrant Box? E.g. running a Nodejs http server on the Vagrant Box, then browsing to localhost:8888 on the Windows host (I see my Hello world now), and then click on a button e.g. 'run cmd.exe' which opens cmd.exe on the Windows host machine? Is the child_process ([link](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)) usable in my scenario?

If it is possible, should the code go within the localexec.js file?

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

Other answers I've found do answer it is possible, but I understand it's only possible from NodeJs when it's installed on the Windows host and is running from the Windows host, not from an external VirtualBox NodeJS server?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using [RPC](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Remote-Procedure-Call) (Remote procedure calls), you must have a server-side in your Windows environment and then you can use this package: [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode), it allows you to listen to receive functions, with those functions you can call commands to cmd and get the stdout from then inside your nodejs boxed vm, you can't communicate from inside your system because VMs are sandboxes, from dnode docs:

```
//Server-Side
var dnode = require('dnode');
var server = dnode({
    transform : function (s, cb) {
        cb(s.replace(/[aeiou]{2,}/, 'oo').toUpperCase())
    }
});
server.listen(5004);

//Client-Side
var dnode = require('dnode');

var d = dnode.connect(5004);
d.on('remote', function (remote) {
    remote.transform('beep', function (s) {
        console.log('beep => ' + s);
        d.end();
    });
});
```

Ps: dnode allows you execute any kind of code you want :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the information. I managed to do it like this : "var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("ipconfig -all", puts);" But I will try your solution too. Thanks